# Update bits error on one testcase

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Given two 32-bit numbers, N and M, and two bit positions, i and j. Write a method to set all bits between i and j in N equal to M (e g , M becomes a substring of N located at i and starting at j)

Example

```
Given N=(10000000000)2, M=(10101)2, i=2, j=6
return N=(10001010100)2
```

Here's my code:

```
class Solution {
/**
 *@param n, m: Two integer
 *@param i, j: Two bit positions
 *return: An integer
 */
public int updateBits(int n, int m, int i, int j) {
    n = clearbits(n,i,j);
    m = m<<i;
    return m|n;
}
public static int clearbits(int n, int i, int j){
    //& with 0
    long allones = ~0;
    long left = allones << (j);
    long right = ((1<<i) - 1);
    long mask  = left | right;
    return (int) mask & n;
}}
```

The problem is for input `[-123,45,21,26]` expected output is `-37748859` and the code is giving output `-123`

Update: After changing clearbits to handle integer overflow . It fails for the following input
 Input
[-521,0,31,31]
Output
-521
Expected
2147483127

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why given that input you're expecting that output?

Comment: Given two 32-bit numbers, N and M, and two bit positions, i and j. Write a method to set all bits between i and j in N equal to M (e g , M becomes a substring of N located at i and starting at j)

Comment: I don't think the example you gave matches the requirements. Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: counting i and j from the left, the ith to jth bits in N have been replaced by those in M. The example does that .

Comment: In `10001010100`, the i-th bit is still 0, why wasn't it replaced by 1? (the corresponding bit in M).

Comment: count i from 0. so 2nd bit would be 3rd from left

Comment: Exactly, that bit is still 0 (from the left). Why it's not 1? That's what I want to understand.

Comment: sorry from the right

Comment: I almost though I'm getting crazy.

Comment: In the problem case, `i + j` exceeds 32.  Is valid input?

Comment: Yes it's a valid input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need really is this:

```
public int updateBits(int n, int m, int i, int j) {
  int mask = ((int)((1L<<(j-i+1))-1))<<(i);
  return (n&~mask)|((m<<i)&mask);
}
```

Note that for debugging purpose, you can use following method to print out the bit string:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(mask));
```

Basically I need to create a mask that matches the bit positions between `i` and `j`. Now Suppose I want to mask between position 3 and 5, I basically want to generate a mask that looks like follows:

```
0000111000
```

I can do this by first trying to generate this:

```
0000000111
```

And shift it by `i` positions to the left. This value `+ 1` gives me:

```
0000001000
```

Which is `1 << (j-i+1)`, and subtracting as in `(1 << (j-i+1))-1` one gives me the mask I still have to further left shift by `i`, so I get this for the mask:

```
((1<<(j-i+1))-1)<<(i)
```

Clearing bits on n is done using `(n&~mask)`.

I cannot directly mask the bits in `m`, as I still need to left shift it so it matches to position of the bit string to be replaced. After shifting, I can mask using `((m<<i)&mask)`. Note that there might not be a need to mask `m`, if the user assures that m fits within the mask.

Now just put the two terms together, and you have the answer!

```
return (n&~mask)|((m<<i)&mask);
```

Or without masking `m`, you do this in one step:

```
return (n&~(((int)((1L<<(j-i+1))-1))<<(i)))|(m<<i);
```

UPDATE:

You follow a slightly different approach, where you construct left and right-side of the mask, and add the two together. Nice approach. However, the one mistake I noticed was this: left should not be `allones << (j+i)` but simply `allones << (j+1)` (plus one, not plus `i`).

We also need to take again care of the overflow:

```
int left = (int)(((long)allones) << (j+1));
```

Comment: gives wrong answer 
Input
[1,-1,0,31]
Output
1
Expected
-1

Comment: Ok ... fixed that too. 1 shifted 31 times to the left doesn't fit an int. So to handle this one case, I temporarily calculate it as a long (`1L`), and downcast it to an int.

Comment: your solution is correct but can u tell the mistake in mine?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, Your mistake is integer overflow.

Comment: Pretty good approach with left/right side of the mask. However, at least one problem is that left should not be `allones << (j+i)` but simply `allones << (j)`

Comment: after doing that it fails for this
Input
[-521,0,31,31]
Output
-521
Expected
2147483127

Comment: Ok ... the j shift was still off by one, and we re-introduced the overflow problem, which needs fixing. Updated answer.

Comment: This additional correction should have fixed it: `int left = (int)(((long)allones) << (j+1));`